# React storybook showing formik form with errors

Tags: reactjs, formik, storybook

What is the simplest way to force a formik form to show fields in error?

I would like to this for a react storybook to show what our form looks like when a field has an error in it.

Each field in my form will only display an error if it has been touched and its value is not valid.

I can set the initial value of the fields but I can't figure out how to mark then all as touched so that the errors are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The [Formik test for ErrorMessage](https://github.com/formium/formik/blob/1a766f187cb6c6d849636bddb1233ddad0d24b96/packages/formik/test/ErrorMessage.test.tsx) might be of some use.

Note the use of setFieldError and [setError](https://github.com/formium/formik/blob/f117c04738ed218b5eb8916d7189e0849962d50d/docs/api/formik.md#seterrors-fields--field-string-string---void)

Comment: Links are broken

Comment: updated so they aren't broken any more. Info might be outdated now though

Answer (score 1):

I managed this by setting `initialErrors` and `initialTouched` for the fields I wanted to display the error state for, in addition to setting `initialValues`.

In the Formik docs:

- https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#initialerrors-formikerrorsvalues
- https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#initialtouched-formiktouchedvalues

eg.

```
<Formik initialValues={} initialErrors={} initialTouched={}>...</Formik>
```

This worked in stories using both a decorator Formik component wrapper as well as the [storybook-formik](https://github.com/bhishp/storybook-formik) addon.